# RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate Doesn;t show map and routes

Tags: android-auto

Hi I'm trying to implement RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate but have some troubles:

1.- Routes List is displayed but the map in background is not showed

2.- For this reason i can't draw the route between my current location and place A or B

this is my code where I build the template, 2 routes and the list of them

```
class RoutePreviewScreen(carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext) {
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
    val builder = RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate.Builder()



    val locationA = CarLocation.create(19.2689369, -103.7636865)
    val locationB = CarLocation.create(19.269160, -103.754996)

    val markerA = PlaceMarker.Builder().setColor(CarColor.RED).build()
    val markerB = PlaceMarker.Builder().setColor(CarColor.BLUE).build()

    val placeA = Place.Builder(locationA).setMarker(markerA).build()
    val placeB = Place.Builder(locationB).setMarker(markerB).build()

    val routeItem = Row.Builder()
        .setTitle(CarText.create("From current to A"))
        .addText(SpannableString(" ").apply {
            setSpan(
                DistanceSpan.create(
                    Distance.create(Math.random() * 100, Distance.UNIT_KILOMETERS)
                ), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
            )
        })
        .addText(SpannableString(" ").apply {
            setSpan(
                DurationSpan.create(
                    Duration.ofHours(3)
                ), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
            )
        })
        .setMetadata(
            Metadata.Builder()
                .setPlace(placeA)
                .build()
        )
        .build()

    val routeItem2 = Row.Builder()
        .setTitle(CarText.create("From current location to A"))
        .addText(SpannableString(" ").apply {
            setSpan(
                DistanceSpan.create(
                    Distance.create(Math.random() * 200, Distance.UNIT_KILOMETERS)
                ), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
            )
        })
        .addText(SpannableString(" ").apply {
            setSpan(
                DurationSpan.create(
                    Duration.ofHours(3)
                ), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
            )
        })
        .setMetadata(
            Metadata.Builder()
                .setPlace(placeB)
                .build()
        )
        .build()


    val itemList = ItemList.Builder()
        .addItem(routeItem)
        .addItem(routeItem2)
        .setOnSelectedListener {
            //TODO SELECTED
        }
        .build()

    builder.setItemList(itemList)

    val navigateAction = Action.Builder()
        .setTitle("Start Navigation")
        .setOnClickListener {
         //TODO IMPLEMENT NAVIGATION
        }
        .build()

    builder.setNavigateAction(navigateAction)

    return builder.build()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Routes List is displayed but the map in background is not showed

For navigation apps (those that use the `NavigationTemplate` and supporting templates like the `MapTemplate`, `RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate`, and `PlaceListNavigationTemplate`), you are responsible for drawing the map yourself. See [Draw the map](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation#drawing-the-map) for more details. https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app-samples/navigation/ also has a sample app that you can reference, with [`SurfaceRenderer`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app-samples/navigation/common/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/sample/navigation/common/car/SurfaceRenderer.java) being of particular interest there.

This is in contrast to point of interest (POI) apps, which use the `PlaceListMapTemplate`, which handles drawing the map and markers for you.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for all your help, i have a little question more, how I could get a map resource as Drawble? i see that the sample use a png image with figures and draw diferent lines.

Or maybe have I to use any google resource in its place?

Comment: Most developers use external services to provide their map tiles. To use Google Maps, there is an SDK for use with Android Auto: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/android-sdk/android-auto. There are also other options like OpenStreetMaps, MapBox (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/v2/guides/androidauto/), and Here maps (https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/sdk-for-android-navigate-developer-guide/page/topics/android-auto.html)